# Devolver ID del Registro Guardado (AJAX - MVC5 - ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, mvc

Tengo un formulario que se envía por Ajax y se almacena correctamente en la base de Datos. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que al momento de guardar, este me devuelva el ID de ese registro que acaba de almacenar?, ya que en otra parte del documento tengo otro formulario que necesita ese ID para editar los campos de ese mismo registro.

**Metodo para Guardar (Controlador)**

```html
 public JsonResult GuardarPropuesta(KaizenViewModel model)
        {
            var estado = false;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var bd = new Modelo())
                {
                    FormPropuesta TempPropuesta = new FormPropuesta
                    {
                        CorreoUsuario = model.FormPropuesta.CorreoUsuario,
                        Nombre = model.FormPropuesta.Nombre,
                        FechaPropuesta = DateTime.Now,
                        Area = model.FormPropuesta.Area,
                        Aporta = model.FormPropuesta.Aporta,
                        SituacionInicial = model.FormPropuesta.SituacionInicial,
                        Que = model.FormPropuesta.Que,
                        QuienPropone = model.FormPropuesta.QuienPropone,
                        QuienBeneficia = model.FormPropuesta.QuienBeneficia,
                        Como = model.FormPropuesta.Como,
                        Cuando = model.FormPropuesta.Cuando,
                        FechaFinal = DateTime.Now,
                        FechaInicio = DateTime.Now,
                        Donde = model.FormPropuesta.Donde,
                        InversionInicial = model.FormPropuesta.InversionInicial,
                        IndicadorClave = model.FormPropuesta.IndicadorClave,
                        FechaImplementacion = DateTime.Now,
                        FechaEvaluacion = DateTime.Now,
                        Estado = FormPropuesta.estado.Revision,
                        BenCualitativo = 0,
                        BenCuantitativo = 0,
                        NivelEsfuerzo = 0,
                        Originalidad = 0,
                        PosibilidadReplicar = 0,
                        Promedio = 0,
                        Puntaje = 0,
                        Observaciones = ""
                    };
                    db.FormPropuesta.Add(TempPropuesta);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                estado = true;
                var result = new { respuesta = estado };
                return Json(result);
            }
            else
            {
                var result = new { respuesta = estado };
                return Json(result);
            }
        }
```

**Ajax (Vista)**

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ContOcultar").show();
        $("#AlertShow").hide();
        $("#ContenedorAlerta").hide();
        $("#FormPropuesta").validate({
            submitHandler: function GuardarPropuesta(){
                var url = "@Url.Action("GuardarPropuesta", "FormPropuestas")";
                var data = $("#FormPropuesta");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data.serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#loader").toggleClass("loader");},
                    success: function (result) {
                        AbrirModalNuevaPropuesta();
                        if (result.respuesta == true) {
                            swal({
                                type: 'success',
                                title: '¡Propuesta creada correctamente!',
                                timer: 3000
                            })
                        }
                        else if (result.respuesta == false) {
                            swal({
                                type: 'error',
                                title: '¡Propuesta no se ha guardada!',
                                timer: 3000
                            })
                        }
                        $("#ContenedorAlerta").show();
                        //$("#ContOcultar").hide();

                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $("#loader").removeClass("loader");
                    },
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Me dieron una ayuda de que a través del **db.SaveChanges()**, este me devuelve el ID de ese registro pero no he podido lograrlo.

**¿Me ayudan por favor?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa los comentarios dentro de este código:

```
 public JsonResult GuardarPropuesta(KaizenViewModel model)
        {
            var estado = false;
            int idModelo = -1;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var bd = new Modelo())
                {
                    FormPropuesta TempPropuesta = new FormPropuesta
                    {
                        CorreoUsuario = model.FormPropuesta.CorreoUsuario,
                        Nombre = model.FormPropuesta.Nombre,
                        FechaPropuesta = DateTime.Now,
                        Area = model.FormPropuesta.Area,
                        Aporta = model.FormPropuesta.Aporta,
                        SituacionInicial = model.FormPropuesta.SituacionInicial,
                        Que = model.FormPropuesta.Que,
                        QuienPropone = model.FormPropuesta.QuienPropone,
                        QuienBeneficia = model.FormPropuesta.QuienBeneficia,
                        Como = model.FormPropuesta.Como,
                        Cuando = model.FormPropuesta.Cuando,
                        FechaFinal = DateTime.Now,
                        FechaInicio = DateTime.Now,
                        Donde = model.FormPropuesta.Donde,
                        InversionInicial = model.FormPropuesta.InversionInicial,
                        IndicadorClave = model.FormPropuesta.IndicadorClave,
                        FechaImplementacion = DateTime.Now,
                        FechaEvaluacion = DateTime.Now,
                        Estado = FormPropuesta.estado.Revision,
                        BenCualitativo = 0,
                        BenCuantitativo = 0,
                        NivelEsfuerzo = 0,
                        Originalidad = 0,
                        PosibilidadReplicar = 0,
                        Promedio = 0,
                        Puntaje = 0,
                        Observaciones = ""
                    };
                    db.FormPropuesta.Add(TempPropuesta);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    idModelo = TempPropuesta.Id; // Aquí lo tienes.
                }
                estado = true;
                // Envías ese id, considera que ese valor de -1 sirve para darte idea si es inexistente o realmente existe.
                var result = new { respuesta = estado, id = idModelo };
                return Json(result);
            }
            else
            {
                var result = new { respuesta = estado, id = idModelo };
                return Json(result);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola amigo, obvio me funciono pero quisiera que me ampliaras información sobre la declaración en -1 (¿si es inexistente o realmente existe?)

Comment: Estoy asumiendo que tu campo de ID es autonumerico por lo cual inicia en 1 y sigue +1... Por lo tanto, un valor inexistente es -1. ¿Me dejo entender la idea?

Comment: Quedo claro, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada hermano. Estamos para servir. Si esta respuesta resolvió tu pregunta, marca ese check verde del lado izquierdo para determinar la aceptación de esta respuesta a tu pregunta. Saludos :D